# jquery append data not working after posting new data with other users

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have this code to add comments on my application after posting the data it doesn't show-up to other users until they refresh the page

```
$("#comm_button").click(function() {
        if (jQuery.trim($("#comm_ta").val()).length < 1) {
            return;
        }

        $("#comm_button").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("#comm_ta").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    var ajaxOpts = {
                        type: "post",
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/moder/add_comment",
                        data: "&content=" + $("#comm_ta").val() + "&thread_id=<?php echo $thread_info['th_id'] ?>&meeting_id=<?php echo $thread_info['meeting_id']; ?>",
                        success: function(data) {
                            if (data != 'bad request') {    

                            $("#all_comments").append(data);
                                $("#all_comments div:last-child").show("slow");
                                $("#comm_ta").val(' ');
                            }

                            $("#comm_button").removeAttr('disabled');
                            $("#comm_ta").removeAttr('disabled');
                        }
                    };

        $.ajax(ajaxOpts);

    });
```

Comment: Have you checked the console to see what the exact response is? Have you debugged in any way? Is `data` not equal to `bad request`? There's a lot of things to investigate here.

Comment: Are you trying to push your post to other users or you are trying to download the updated list of posts?

Comment: You are not pushing the comment to other users. You are just add it to the current page. If you want the comment to be visible to all users you need to build a push or pull mechanism into it.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan no errors in the console ,,,no bad request it's working fine and the new post added to the previous comments in my page but the other users have to refresh the page to see it

Comment: @Alexus yes i'm trying to push the comment to other user to they can but their comments

Comment: What is the response status of the ajax?

Comment: @S.Pols can you explain a little more ??

Comment: In what way is another user notified of the comments you are posting? You need to create an pull script or something like that which checks each x seconds if there is a new comment. Then if there is get it with an AJAX request and append it to the div.

Comment: $("#all_comments").append(data); isn't this suppose to work ??

Comment: Yes it will, only on the current client. Not on every client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is executed on your local machine and doesn't affect other users/browsers in any way.

You need 3 things here:

1. AJAX call to submit the comment to the server as well as append it for the user posting.
2. Server side handler to recieve and store the comment in the database.
3. AJAX call to fetch the new posted comments so that other users could pull them as they get stored on the server.